# Using the + operator to combine arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've recently discovered that `+` may be used to combine arrays in PHP.

**Add an associative array to an associative array:**

```
$array1 = ["The" => "quick", "brown" => "fox"];
$array2 = ["jumps" => "over", "the" => "lazy dog"];

$combinedArray = $array1 + $array2;

/* Gives:

Array
(
    [The] => quick
    [brown] => fox
    [jumps] => over
    [the] => lazy dog
)

*/
```

**Add an associative array to an indexed array:**

```
$array1 = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"];
$array2 = ["jumps" => "over", "the" => "lazy dog"];

$combinedArray = $array1 + $array2;

/* Gives:

Array
(
    [0] => The
    [1] => quick
    [2] => brown
    [3] => fox
    [jumps] => over
    [the] => lazy dog
)

*/
```

**Add an indexed array to an associative array:**

```
$array1 = ["The" => "quick", "brown" => "fox"];
$array2 = ["jumps", "over", "the", "lazy dog"];

$combinedArray = $array1 + $array2;

/* Gives:

Array
(
    [The] => quick
    [brown] => fox
    [0] => jumps
    [1] => over
    [2] => the
    [3] => lazy dog
)

*/
```

**Add an indexed array to an indexed array:**

```
$array1 = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"];
$array2 = ["jumps", "over", "the", "lazy dog"];

$combinedArray = $array1 + $array2;

/* Gives:

Array
(
    [0] => The
    [1] => quick
    [2] => brown
    [3] => fox
)

*/
```

One of these is not like the others.

Why isn't the last one working?

Comment: From the docs "for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored"

Comment: Because of the same indexes. Change `"the" => "lazy dog"` to `"The" => "lazy dog"` in your first example and see what the result is

Comment: For the last one , Try to use + on two arrays of different sizes (left hand one: 4 elements),  (right hand one: 5 elements) and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because both arrays in the last example have the same keys:

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)